# "Form{" returning "Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure" error

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code that returns the aforementioned

> Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration'
> that does not accept a closure

error on the line with `Form{`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ReminderDetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var reminder: Reminder
    
    var body: some View {
        Form { //Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure
            Section(header: Text("Name")) {
                TextField("Name", text: $reminder.name)
            }
            Section(header: Text("Due Date")) {
                DatePicker("Due Date", selection: $reminder.dueDate, displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])
            }
            Section(header: Text("Notes")) {
                TextEditor(text: $reminder.notes)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Edit Reminder")
    }
}
```

I have tried following the `Form` with brackets like this: `Form(){`.

Comment: There is probably a typo somewhere. Comment out each section until you find it, btw that TextEditor looks suspicious

Comment: What do you mean by "that TextEditor looks suspicious"? Are you suggesting that may be the issue?

Comment: I added my own implementation of `Reminder` and it compiled fine. Please add your `Reminder` class

Comment: Maybe, in proper convention plurals are usually arrays and you are using it as a string but that may be just a typo, that is why I say suspicious. Just comment out the sections you will be able to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Including the code for the Reminder class might be helpful

Comment: I am using CoreData to store the Reminder class. Here is the Reminder+CoreDataClass.swift file:


`import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Reminder)
public class Reminder: NSManagedObject {

}`

Comment: I apologise for my naivety, I'm just starting out with Xcode and SwiftUI. Where is the entity definition?

Comment: In your Core Data model

Comment: Is this it? (Use of "("at"symbol)" to represent @ otherwise Stackoverflow blocks comment.

'import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Reminder {

    ("at"symbol)nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Reminder> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Reminder>(entityName: "Reminder")
    }

    ("at"symbol)NSManaged public var name: String?
    ("at"symbol)NSManaged public var descriptionText: String?
    ("at"symbol)NSManaged public var dueDate: Date?
    ("at"symbol)NSManaged public var repeatType: String?

}

extension Reminder : Identifiable {

}'

Comment: Yes that is it but you should add code like this to your question instead to make the question clearer and because it's hard to read code posted in the comments.

Comment: The problem is that your attributes in `Reminder` are all optional but TextField, DatePicker etc requires a Binding to a non optional attribute

Answer (score 3):

If you get that error, then you have a problem within your brackets.
The error there makes the compiler believe you want to use the second `init` version, which takes a `FormStyleConfiguration` as a parameter:

```
struct Form<Content> where Content : View {
   init(content: () -> Content) {...}
   init(_ configuration: FormStyleConfiguration){...}
   ...
}
```

Correct the problem within the brackets, and the `Form` will work again. The simplest way to find the problem is to comment out the `Form {` line and the closing bracket line `}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that headers are not passed in the correct order to the `Section` initializer. It should appear after the content (see [the `init(content:header:)` initializer signature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/section/init(content:header:)-29e2l).

Every time you use a header I would change it to (for example):

```swift
Section {
    TextField("Name", text: $reminder.name)
} header: {
    Text("Name")
}
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

For me it was accessing a property var with function calling parenthesis.

e.g.

`person.salary` vs `person.salary()`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same *error message* which, I think, is *misleading* for my case. I added a new view, `NewView(title: String)`, to a `Form`, and I forgot to pass the argument, `title`:

```
Form {
  ...
  // Problematic code
  NewView() // <== This causes the error
```

Solution

```
Form {
  ...
  NewView(title: "My Title") // <== Passing 'title' fixes the error.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Try to use:

```
Section("Notes") {
  TextField("Placeholder text", text: $reminder.notes)
}
```