# I'm writing code for a small app. But I keep getting an error

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm writing code for a small app. But I keep getting an error
The error I keep getting is "Trailing closure passed to a parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure". Please help me out.

I can't find any solution for it. i can provide more detail if you guys want me to. but i need a solution for it.

```
Form {
            Section {
                TextField(text: replicatestuff.$prompt,
                          prompt: Text("Enter a prompt to display an image"),
                          axis: .vertical,
                          label: {})
                .disabled(replicatestuff.prediction?.status.terminated == false)
                    .submitLabel(.go)
                    .onSubmit(of: .text) {
                        Task {
                            try! await replicatestuff.generate()
                        }
                    }
            }
            
            if let prediction = replicatestuff.prediction {
                ZStack {
                    Color.clear
                        .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                    
                    switch replicatestuff.prediction.status {
                    case .starting, .processing:
                        VStack{
                            ProgressView("Generating...")
                                .padding(32)
                            
                            Button("Cancel") {
                                Task { try await replicatestuff.cancel() }
                            }
                        }
                    case .failed:
                        Text(replicatestuff.prediction.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    case .succeeded:
                        if let url = replicatestuff.prediction.output?.first {
                            VStack {
                                AsyncImage(url: url, scale: 2.0, content: { phase in
                                    phase.image?
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(32)
                                })
                                
                                ShareLink("Export", item: url)
                                    .padding(32)

                            }
                        }
                    case .canceled:
                        Text("The prediction was canceled")
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                .padding()
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                .listRowInsets(.init())
            }
        }
        
        Spacer()
```

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the error?

Comment: It is a typo somewhere, comment out sections until you find it

Comment: I think this is the same as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75524635/form-returning-trailing-closure-passed-to-parameter-of-type-formstyleconfig).

Answer (score 1):

You cast the (assumed) optional `replicateStuff.prediction` to a non-optional constant called `prediction` at the start:

```swift
if let prediction = replicatestuff.prediction {
```

but then further in the code you attempt to use the `replicateStuff.prediction` which is still an optional type.

```swift
switch replicatestuff.prediction.status {
```

That can't be since `replicateStuff.prediction` is an optional (I presume). So you should be using the non-optional `prediction` everyewhere instead

```swift
prediction.status {
```

I hope this ends up being your issue.